Google Analytics in Chrome Extension isn't remembering users with given Client ID
I have a chrome extension and I want to track analytics.
Sending an event is fine, but, remembering users doesn't seem to be working.
Google is showing every user as new; therefore, when I look at retention, there is no user retention at all.
I'm using this as per the documentation and everything seems to be working when I console log the client ID and session IDs.
Is it a setting in Google Analytics that I'm missing?
I'm building the chrome extension using ReactJS.
I followed this documentation:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/how-to/integrate/google-analytics-4

import { API } from '../../data/GAnalytics';

export const fetchClientId = async () => {
    if (chrome && chrome.storage) {
        console.log("chrome.storage is available");
        const result = await chrome.storage.local.get('clientId');
        let clientId = result.clientId;

        if (!clientId) {
            clientId = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1)).join();
            console.log("Generating new clientId:", clientId);
            await chrome.storage.local.set({ clientId });
        }

        return clientId;
    } else {
        console.error("chrome.storage.local is not available in this context.");
    }
}

export const fetchSessionId = async () => {
    if (chrome && chrome.storage) {
        const result = await chrome.storage.local.get('sessionId');
        let sessionId = result.sessionId;

        if (!sessionId) {
            sessionId = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1)).join();
            await chrome.storage.local.set({ sessionId });
        }

        return sessionId;
    }
}

export const sendEvent = async (eventName, params) => {
    const clientId = await fetchClientId();
    console.log('Client ID:', clientId);
    const sessionId = await fetchSessionId();
    console.log('Session ID:', sessionId);

    const GA_ENDPOINT = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect';
    const MEASUREMENT_ID = API.measurement_id;
    const API_SECRET = API.api_secret;

    fetch(
        `${GA_ENDPOINT}?measurement_id=${MEASUREMENT_ID}&api_secret=${API_SECRET}`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                client_id: clientId,
                events: [
                    {
                        name: eventName,
                        params: {
                            session_id: sessionId,
                            ...params,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }),
        }
    );
}


export const sendPageView = async () => {
    const clientId = await fetchClientId();

    const GA_ENDPOINT = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/mp/collect';
    const MEASUREMENT_ID = API.measurement_id;
    const API_SECRET = API.api_secret;
    const DEFAULT_ENGAGEMENT_TIME_IN_MSEC = 10 * 1000;

    fetch(
        `${GA_ENDPOINT}?measurement_id=${MEASUREMENT_ID}&api_secret=${API_SECRET}`,
        {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                client_id: clientId,
                events: [
                    {
                        name: 'page_view',
                        params: {
                            session_id: await fetchSessionId(),
                            engagement_time_msec: DEFAULT_ENGAGEMENT_TIME_IN_MSEC,
                            page_title: document.title,
                            page_location: document.location.href,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            }),
        }
    );
}

{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "xxx",
  "description": "xxx",
  "permissions": [
    "history",
    "storage",
    "topSites"  ],
  "short_name": "React Extension",
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/icon16.png",
    "32": "/images/icon48.png",
    "48": "/images/icon48.png",
    "128": "/images/icon128.png"
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "popup.html"
  }
}


Why would you use console log for debugging? Go to your network panel and see what your extension actually sends to GA, what's the client id there. Reproduce the problem. Plus, you're not linking to the documentation you're using for this.

Hi @BNazaruk
This is what is actually sent to GA:
{client_id: "995276708", events: [{name: "answerChosen",…}]}
client_id
:
"995276708"
events
:
[{name: "answerChosen",…}]
0
:
{name: "answerChosen",…}
name
:
"answerChosen"
params
:
{session_id: "2091310225", answer: "Costa Rica", correct: true, game: "countryFromFlag",…}
answer
:
"Costa Rica"
correct
:
true
game
:
"countryFromFlag"
method
:
"mouseClick"
session_id
:
"2091310225"

Client ID does remain the same. So, why isn't GA picking it up?

probably malformed requests. Check the Debug View. Realistically, I would suggest to never use the MP. It's brutal. Better package your gtag library with the extension and use gtag's api to send events. Not sure if gtag would enjoy working in the background worker though. If not, then just form the requests as gtag forms them cuz then at least you have plenty of working examples even here, on this page when you look for the "collect" network requests.
